# md5sum problems when string has \n characters in it

Tags: linux, md5sum

I have the following issue when trying to correctly hash a string on Linux.

I am using the following process on a linux shell command:

```
echo -n "THIS IS A TEST" | md5sum
```

and it is producing the correct md5 value (`1586CFFAFA39E38959477DA9EAA41C31`)

However I cannot figure out how to get the correct md5 value for the string: `THIS IS\n A TEST`

I tried the similar:

```
echo -n "THIS IS\n A TEST" | md5sum
```

that gives a wrong md5 value instead of the correct one which should be: `180FB5A20D21A215AF9D1F89251B3614`

Comment: Depending on which `echo` you use, you may have to use `-e`. Does `echo -n "THIS IS\n A TEST"` print an actual newline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `echo -e` (using Bash) to make it understand escape codes.

Eg: 
    echo -en "THIS IS\n A TEST" | md5sum

This will give you the correct hash for that string (which is) : `7a04591799701f311f30755bf53f90d1`

Comment: Note that OP disagrees with you on what the correct value is!

Comment: @chiastic-security I've seen that, but I've been testing in python, and the values he gives is for "THIS IS\n A TEST" with a *escaped* \n (literal antislash then `n`)... Which is weird.